# Why can't I see my laser?

Tags: laser-diode

I recently took apart 2 DVD readers? Might have been burners too, but my question is why can't I see the lasers? I tried using both 2 and 4 AA batteries hooked up according to this diagram http://d13z1xw8270sfc.cloudfront.net/origin/58770/diode_wiring_diagram.jpg . I can feel the diode heating up after about 5 seconds, but I can't see the actual laser. Thanks for the help.

Comment: connecting the diode with 2 or 4 AA battery without resistor would very likely destroy the diode

Comment: Oh crap, what's the correct voltage to use then? All the youtube videos I saw had them use 2 AA batteries

Comment: Not sure, maybe vary, from this http://danyk.cz/laser3_en.html tutorial it stated: "The voltage drop of infrared laser diode is 2.15 V and the voltage drop of red one is 2.5 V". If you are using higher voltage, you should use current limiting resistor or current regulator

Comment: If you did happen to light the laser diode and shined it into your eye you may have damaged your eye to the point of not being able to see it!!

Comment: Which is why, in some circles, a tshirt is often referred to which says, "Do not look into laser beam with remaining good eye."

Comment: No, I aimed it at somewhere else and looked at it from the side. An AA battery is around 2.5V right? So a single AA battery should be able to power it? Assuming I didn't fry it already.

Comment: standard an AA battery ~ 1.5 volt, sometimes fresh alkaline zinc battery 1.6v, another chemisty can reach 1.8v

Comment: @nadjatee1996 - Stop. Just stop. You cannot drive a laser diode directly from a battery. Don't even think about it. You must use a current regulator of some sort, even if it's just a resistor.

Comment: I am using a resistor...Sorry I didn't make that clear. I just wasn't sure how many batteries to use. I can still feel the heat using one battery, but no visible laser.

Comment: Just be careful to not, under any circumstances, point the beam (visible or not) to your or someone else's eyes, or you will risk not see the laser or anything else anymore!

Comment: There is no correct voltage.   http://www.teamwavelength.com/info/laserdiodedrivers.php

Comment: By correct, I mostly just meant enough to power it, but not enough to fry it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the rep to comment, but it sounds like the answer to your question is that the diode may be working and you can't see the light because infrared is outside of the visible spectrum.

Comment: why would you need a rep to comment? If you think you know the answer

Comment: CD-only readers used IR lasers.  DVD readers need a shorter wavelength--visible red, I think.  BluRay should be self-explanatory.

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot. Last question is it normal for those IR lasers emit a lot of heat?

Answer (score 0):

There are lasers with all kinds of wavelengths.
Only a small part of the EM (electromagnetic) spectrum is visible light. So it's possible it is in the infra red range. You can often see IR light with a digital camera.
Also never look directly into the laser also invisible light can burn or harm your eyes.
[image: visible light spectrum]